# What is the orbital angular velocity of a satellite?

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, time-dilation, angular-velocity, satellites

Angular velocity ω is by definition the runned angle $dθ$ per time $dt$ elapsed: $ω=dθ/dt$. If the time elapsed in a specific point on the earth's surface is $dt$, the dilated time elapsed on satellite is $dt′$. What is the satellite's orbital angular speed? Is it $dθ/dt$ or $dθ/dt′$?

Comment: Orbital angular velocity is invariant.So the relative orbital angular velocity is dθ/dt = dθ/dt'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only relative velocity is physically meaningful.We can choose either satellite or earth to be at rest.So the relative orbital angular velocity is dθ/dt = dθ/dt'